# Implement RxJs operator instead of nested subscribe blocks

Tags: angular, rxjs, graphql, angular-router, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm getting an `id` from the **route params** and that I'm passing to my API call. For this, I'm currently using **nested subscription**. But I want to use the `concat()` or maybe some other operator of **RxJs**(I don't know which) so that I can avoid nesting. Since the docs [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html) is not giving some example, which left me confused regarding, how I can use it here in my code.

Below is code where nesting is implemented, I want to implement same logic using `concat()` or maybe some other operator of RxJs.

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
  this.selectedPostId = +params['id'];
  if (this.selectedPostId) {
    // Simple GraphQL API call below
    this.apollo.watchQuery(GetPost, {id: this.selectedPostId})
      .subscribe((post: PostType) => {
        if (post) {
          console.log(post);
        }
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: You can't use concat, you need the output from the first observable as an input to the second. You could use filter and flatMap (with pipe, depending on the RxJS version).

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you tell me how can I use that?

Comment: Can you spend more than one minute looking into it yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator you really want is `flatMap`

```
import { map, flatMap, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...


this.route.params.pipe(
        map((params: Params) => +params['id']), // Get the ID param
        filter((selectedPostId: any) => selectedPostId), // Remove any events without an ID
        flatMap(id => this.apollo.watchQuery(GetPost, {id: selectedPostId})) // Call the watchQuery function
    ).subscribe((post: PostType) => {
        if (post) {
          console.log(post);
        }
    });
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well spotted, bad copy paste job there from me

Comment: @user184994  `TypeError: this.route.params.map is not a function` though I have imported

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik as mentioned in my comment, newer versions of RxJS will need `.pipe`.